# Loading gif in a SharePoint 2013 page

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

The expected functionality is: on button click, a PPT gets downloaded(this comes from a REST call from an external site), in the meantime when the PPT is getting downloaded, a loading gif should be shown in the page and it should be stopped after the PPT is downloaded.
I've tried setTimeout() function, but it doesn't seem to be working right in this case.
Is it possible to implement through jQuery or javascript? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My test code:

```
<img src="/_layouts/15/images/loading16.GIF" style="display: none;" id="img">
<input type="button" value="download" id="download">
<script src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/sprestlib@1.8.0/dist/sprestlib.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $("#download").click(function(){
    $("#img").css("display","");
    sprLib.file('Doc/Presentation.pptx').get()
      .then(function (blob) {
        var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", url);
        link.setAttribute("download", _fileName);
        link.style = "visibility:hidden";
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        setTimeout(function () { document.body.removeChild(link); }, 500);
      }).then(function(){
        $("#img").css("display","none");
      });
  })    
</script>
```

Test result:
[image]

Comment: is it possible to dynamically set the time in the setTimeout(function())?, because ppt generation varies with selection of project in my requirement.

Comment: The setTimeout method removes the created a element and it does not control the display time of the gif. In the second then method, the gif is hidden after the download is completed.